# ¿Cómo implementar bien paramMap en esta situacion Angular?

Tags: angular, angular11

Estaba siguiendo un video para consumir la API de Rick y Morty y me encontré en una situación que no se como salir

```
import { CharacterService } from './../../../../shared/services/character.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Character} from "@app/shared/interfaces/character.interface";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';


type RequestInfo = {
  next: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-character-list',
  templateUrl: './character-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./character-list.component.scss']
})
export class CharacterListComponent implements OnInit {
  characters:Character[] = [];
  info: RequestInfo={
    next: ''
  }
  private query: string = '';
  private pageNum=1;
  private hideScrolHeight = 200;
  private showScrolHeight = 500;



  constructor(private characterSvc: CharacterService, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCharactersByQuery();
  }

  private getCharactersByQuery(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      
    });
  }

  private getDataFromService():void{
    this.characterSvc.searchCharacters(this.query, this.pageNum)
    .pipe(
      take(1)
      ).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        // console.log('reponse->', res);
        // const {info, results} = res;
        // this.characters =[...this.characters, ...results];
        // this.info = info;
        if (res?.results?.length) {
          const { info, results } = res;
          this.characters = [...this.characters, ...results];
          this.info = info;
        } else {
          this.characters = [];
        }

      })
  }

}
```

¿Qué es lo que pasa en la funcion getCharactersByQuery() que al llegar a la parte de `.subscribe((params: ParamMap)` me salta este error?

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?:
> PartialObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(params: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver | undefined'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(params: ParamMap) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'

Ahora no se que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

`ParamMap` es la interfaz de angular. En el `subscribe` no puedes esperar eso porque la variable `params` tendrá la "forma"(shape) de los parametros que hay en tu ruta.

Por ejemplo, estas en la ruta `https://localhost:4201/post/1/post-1` y en tu `router.module.ts` tienes definida la ruta así.

```javascript
{
  path: 'post/:id/:slug',
  component: PostComponent
}
```

Los parámetros de la ruta (`:id` y `:slug`) serán los params que recibirás en el subscribe. Por lo tanto, tienes que crearte tu interfaz para describir esos params que esperas.

```js
// define la interfaz en tu fichero ts
interface RouteParams {
  id: string;
  slug: string;
}

private getCharactersByQuery(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((params: RouteParams) => {
      // params será un objeto que tendrá { id: 21312321, slug: 'post-1'}
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar algo asi:

```
private getDataFromService():void{
this.characterSvc.searchCharacters(this.query, this.pageNum)
.pipe(
 map((res: any) => {
    // Te recomendaria colocar un console.log(res); para que compruebes que funciona el map.
    // console.log('reponse->', res);
    // const {info, results} = res;
    // this.characters =[...this.characters, ...results];
    // this.info = info;
    if (res?.results?.length) {
      const { info, results } = res;
      this.characters = [...this.characters, ...results];
      this.info = info;
    } else {
      this.characters = [];
    }
 })
)
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estuve viendo tienes que editar la forma del método getCharactersByQuery()
Tiene que quedar asi.

```
  private getCharactersByQuery(): void {
    
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(params=>{
     /* console.log('params->',params)*/
 this.query = params['q'];
      this.getDataFromService();
    });
  }
```

y también puedes seguir el código y agregar un método para recargar luego de la búsqueda

```
private onUrlChanged(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.characters = [];
        this.pageNum = 1;
        this.getCharactersByQuery();
      });
  }
```

ese método lo tienes que llamar del constructor, y el código completo quedaría así:

```
type RequestInfo = {
  next: string;
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-character-list',
  templateUrl: './character-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./character-list.component.scss'],
})
export class CharacterListComponent implements OnInit {
  characters: Character[] = [];
  info: RequestInfo = {
    next: null!,

  };

  private pageNum = 1;
  private query!: string;
  private hideScrollheight = 200;
  private showScrollheight = 500;
 


  constructor(
    private characterSvc: CharacterService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router:Router
  ) {this.onUrlChanged();}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCharactersByQuery();

  }
  private onUrlChanged(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.characters = [];
        this.pageNum = 1;
        this.getCharactersByQuery();
      });
  }

  private getCharactersByQuery(): void {
    
    this.route.queryParams.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(params=>{
      console.log('params->',params)
 this.query = params['q'];
      this.getDataFromService();
    });
  }
 
  private getDataFromService(): void {

    this.characterSvc.searchCharacter(this.query, this.pageNum)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        if (res?.results?.length) {
          const { info, results } = res;
          this.characters = [...this.characters, ...results];
          this.info = info;
        } else {
          this.characters = [];

        }
      });
  }



}
```